# Is it possible to see everything that's tagged with "arrays" but *not* also tagged with "javascript"?

Tags: support, tags, search

Or alternatively, everything that's tagged with "arrays" and also tagged with "C"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sure, just search for [`[arrays] -[javascript]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays+-javascript) or [`[arrays] [c]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arrays+c).